# Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine XML document is too long. hr = 0x80070018

Tags: sql-server, vss

I have about 1400 SQL databases on my environment (on 3 different volumes).
I've got follow errors during taking VSS snap. Also SQLWriter goes from stable to failed "nonretryable"

*Event ID 8193, Source VSS. 
Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine XML document is too long. hr = 0x80070018, The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect. Operation: Writer Modifying Modifying Backup Document Context: Execution Context: Requestor Writer Instance ID: {14BE9B90-62D7-4A2D-B57F-53D21EAB0789}

Event ID 8193, Source VSS. 
Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine IXMLDOMNode::replaceChild. hr = 0x80070057, The parameter is incorrect. Operation: Processing Writer Data Executing Asynchronous Operation Context:Current State: DoSnapshotSet*

When I take snap just for one volume, it works fine. How I can resolve the issue?

Comment: [See this MSDN blog link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2013/08/27/missing-system-writer-case-explained.aspx).  Includes troubleshooting/debugging information and a possible hotfix.

Comment: Thank you HopelessN00b. But unfortunatelly KB mentioned on your link didn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is well documented. Check this link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/event-id-8193-when-you-perform-backup

Comment: At least some hints or summary would be nice. Can you edit your post and add some?

Comment: Good day @ppuschmann, I gave more information in the [QnA forums](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/497084/sql-backup-volume-shadow-copy-service-error-unexpe.html), where you can read it.

Comment: Yes, this this might be great, but one of the ideas of StackExchange/StackOverflow/serverfault is to have the information and answers in this platform and not to rely on external parties.

Comment: And one of my ideas is not to spend time on duplicate posts. When there is a good blog with a full answer, then we should not copy it and change some words in order to re-publish it to promote a different site/company/person/service. Moreover, I hate to spend my time in StackExchange/StackOverflow/serverfault/<> where people do not say thanks. the discussion is limited to short comments, poor interface with simple text only without WYSIWUG editor for discussion, and no no hierarchy structure for comments like forums in 1999 and above all I hate the downvote option. let me find the thread...

Comment: [I think this is the thread I meant to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/497084/sql-backup-volume-shadow-copy-service-error-unexpe.html). I hope this helpful

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes, maybe we should have stayed at NNTP and mailing-lists.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue with the help of Microsoft support (Thank you Fabrizio)

The issue seems to be with the VSS metadata max filesize which is limited to 16MB. This can be increased to 32, 64 or 128 according to your needs. RegKey SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSS\Settings “MaxXmlDocumentSizeMB”.

A detailed exaplanation [SQL VSS BACKUP: UNEXPECTED ERROR CALLING ROUTINE XML DOCUMENT IS TOO LONG](https://www.storcom.com/sql-vss-backup-unexpected-error-calling-routine-xml-document-is-too-long/)

Regards,
Dardan